VisualGDB CTRL-CLICK .CPP
In VisualGDB for Windows, when I CTRL-click on a function call from a .cpp source, the cursor goes to the function declaration in the header file instead of the function definition in the .cpp file.
This problem seems to occur in only one project.
I have deleted all cache directories and re-built the project.
